# find index positions with 3d-array with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVsc3.png)

[target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lclze.png)

im trying to find a rectangle on an image. the background on the image is black but it is actually varaible so it wont be always black. my first attmept was to use open cv2.matchtemplate but it didnt work well because of the noises of the background would give wrong detection. so im trying numpy to check if image array has target array in it and returns index if so but i dont know how im supposed to do so. so far i've figured how to get index using color match like the code below.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
template = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
target = cv2.imread('target.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)


index_pos = np.where((template[:,:,0]==116) & (template[:,:,1]==148) & 
(template[:,:,2]==208))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the image to grayscale using cv2.cvtColor.
2. Apply Gaussian blur to the image using cv2.GaussianBlur. This will help smooth out any noise and make it easier to detect the edges of the rectangle.
3. Use the Canny edge detection algorithm to detect the edges of the rectangle. You can do this using cv2.Canny.
4. Find the contours of the image using cv2.findContours.
5. Use the contours to approximate the shape of the rectangle. You can do this by iterating through the contours and finding the contour with four points that form a rectangle.
6. Once you have found the rectangle, you can use its coordinates to determine its location on the image

Comment: dont you think its better to just find the index using numpy than doing all the things you mentioned since it'd be faster and has 100% chance of finding it

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np


# Create a 3D NumPy array
arr = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]])

# Find the index positions of all elements that are greater than 5
index_positions = np.where(arr > 5)

print(index_positions)
```

Comment: this is just for finding a single element in a subarray..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).